# Retrofit crashes when I throw an exception in an interceptor

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I have an interceptor that handles some authentication things. If the authentication fails it throws and Exception. According to what I could find throwing an exception should result in onFailure getting called where I handle the exception. Unfortunatly this does not happen and the app simply crashes completely. I am sure I must be missing something but I cant seem to figure it out. Hope someone here can help :)

Code and stack trace below:

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
     // Add interceptor that throws
     .addInterceptor { chain ->
         throw Exception("test")
     }
     .build()

retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .client(client)
                .build()

api = retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)


// Create api call...

apicall.enqueue(object : Callback<T> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>?, response: retrofit2.Response<T>?) {
        // ....
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>?, t: Throwable?) {
        // Expect to go here to handle the Exception. But the app crashes
    }
})
```

Stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
                  Process: com.testapp.test.debug, PID: 28891
                  java.lang.Error: java.lang.Exception: test
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1168)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                   Caused by: java.lang.Exception: test
                      at com.testapp.test.data.networking.RetrofitWebApi$client$1.intercept(RetrofitWebApi.kt:90)
                      at com.testapp.test.data.networking.RetrofitWebApi$client$1.intercept(RetrofitWebApi.kt:76)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                      at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
                      at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
                      at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Try to throw IOException maybe

Comment: May be this can help you > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697459/handle-exceptions-thrown-by-a-custom-okhttp-interceptor-in-kotlin-coroutines/65469952#65469952

Answer (score 43, accepted):

OkHttp will only catch the exception that happens in the `Interceptor` if it's an `IOException`. You can see the code that does this [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/b086b8d1835bcb3825d60ceb44bec7dec356405b/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/connection/RealCall.kt), the relevant parts (simplified) are as below:

```
try {
  Response response = getResponseWithInterceptorChain();
} catch (IOException e) {
  responseCallback.onFailure(RealCall.this, e);
}
```

So if you change your code to the following, you'll get a callback in your `onFailure` method as expected:

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
     // Add interceptor that throws
     .addInterceptor { chain ->
         throw IOException("test")
     }
     .build()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should never throw exception which is not `IOException` in OkHttp's `Interceptor` since it will not handled by OkHttp.

Check below source code from OkHttp's `RealCall.java`:

[image]